# Create a word file with csv file or directly from AngularJS website

Tags: angularjs, node.js, excel, csv, ms-word

I got a nodeJS/AngularJS website my client would like to export some data in CSV.
I use ng-csv for doing it, but now he would like to have a word design file.

I don't find a lot of things about this on the web, what is possible to do ?
Transform the csv File from Excel into Word File ?
Or create a word file directly from the website ?

EDIT : I would like to export my data into a Word and display it like this :

[image]

Comment: A csv file is a text file and therefore can be opened in Microsoft Word. You need to be more specific what kind of Word file you would like to have.

Comment: I would like to display the data nicely, display every line from csv in word with a tabulation between every column for exemple

Comment: You're allowed to update your question with this information! So other people can help you even better. Make an example what you want (maybe a screenshot or create an image). Be specific! If you don't know how it should look like, how should we ;-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The better approach I would suggest is that u should create word documnet in node itself, try using officgen module in npm.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/officegen

Comment: That is not @vodet doubt.Vodet want to convert csv data to word

Comment: No if I have to do it directly from the website it's ok